# Roslyn: workspace loads in console application but not in msbuild task

Tags: c#, windows, roslyn

I have a custom msbuild task with this command:

```
var workspace = Workspace.LoadStandAloneProject(csprojPath);
```

When I run it, it throws the following error:

```
  System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Roslyn.Utilities.SerializableDataStorage'.
  Source=Roslyn.Services
  StackTrace:
       at Roslyn.Utilities.RemoteServices.CreateInstance[T]()
       at Roslyn.Services.Host.TemporaryStorageServiceFactory.CreateService(IWorkspaceServiceProvider workspaceServices)
       at Roslyn.Services.Host.WorkspaceServiceProviderFactory.Provider.c__DisplayClass7.b__4()
       at Roslyn.Utilities.NonReentrantLazy`1.get_Value()
       at Roslyn.Services.Host.WorkspaceServiceProviderFactory.Provider.GetService[TWorkspaceService]()
       at Roslyn.Services.SolutionServices..ctor(IWorkspaceServiceProvider workspaceServices, ILanguageServiceProviderFactory languageServicesFactory)
       at Roslyn.Services.Solution..ctor(SolutionId id, String filePath, VersionStamp version, VersionStamp latestProjectVersion, ILanguageServiceProviderFactory languageServiceProviderFactory, IWorkspaceServiceProvider workspaceServices)
       at Roslyn.Services.Host.SolutionFactoryServiceFactory.SolutionFactoryService.CreateSolution(SolutionId id)
       at Roslyn.Services.Host.TrackingWorkspace.CreateNewSolution(ISolutionFactoryService solutionFactory, SolutionId id)
       at Roslyn.Services.Host.TrackingWorkspace..ctor(IWorkspaceServiceProvider workspaceServiceProvider, Boolean enableBackgroundCompilation, Boolean enableInProgressSolutions)
       at Roslyn.Services.Host.HostWorkspace..ctor(IWorkspaceServiceProvider workspaceServiceProvider, Boolean enableBackgroundCompilation, Boolean enableInProgressSolutions, Boolean enableFileTracking)
       at Roslyn.Services.Host.LoadedWorkspace..ctor(ILanguageServiceProviderFactory languageServiceProviderFactory, IWorkspaceServiceProvider workspaceServiceProvider, IProjectFileService projectFileFactsService, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, Boolean enableBackgroundCompilation, Boolean enableFileTracking)
       at Roslyn.Services.Host.LoadedWorkspace..ctor(ExportProvider exportProvider, Boolean solutionLoadOnly, Boolean enableFileTracking)
       at Roslyn.Services.Host.LoadedWorkspace..ctor(Boolean enableFileTracking)
       at Roslyn.Services.Host.LoadedWorkspace.LoadStandAloneProject(String projectFileName, String configuration, String platform, String language, Boolean enableFileTracking)
       at Roslyn.Services.Workspace.LoadStandAloneProject(String projectFileName, String configuration, String platform, String language, Boolean enableFileTracking)
       ...
```

The same code, when run in a console application, with the same project, runs fine.

Any ideas? Googling has not been helpful!

Comment: Same issue here. Anyone?

Comment: @kzu looks like someone has answered.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample MsBuild task with Roslyn.

In order to reconstruct the command line needed by the Workspace.LoadProjectFromCommandLineArguments method, we have to pass some info from the msbuild file into our task.

- The referenced assemblies: the
  @(ReferencePath) item group.
- The cs files to be compiled: the @(Compile) item group.
- The base directory: the $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) built-in property.

That's all that Roslyn needs to parse your source files. (See the note at the end of this post.)

So create a C# class library project.
These are the project references that you'll need:

```
Microsoft.Build.Framework
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0
Roslyn.Compilers
Roslyn.Services
```

The code for the custom MsBuild task:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using Roslyn.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RoslynMsBuildTask
{
    public class RoslynTask : Task
    {
        [Required]
        public ITaskItem[] ReferencePath { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ITaskItem[] Compile { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ITaskItem BaseDirectory { get; set; }

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "RoslynTask.Execute called...\n");

            // Format the command line with the minimal info needed for Roslyn to create a workspace.
            var commandLineForProject = string.Format("/reference:{0} {1}",
                ReferencePath.Select(i => i.ItemSpec).ToSingleString(",", "\"", "\""),
                Compile.Select(i => i.ItemSpec).ToSingleString(" ", "\"", "\""));

            // Create the Roslyn workspace.
            var workspace = Workspace.LoadProjectFromCommandLineArguments("MyProject", "C#", commandLineForProject, BaseDirectory.ItemSpec);

            // Make sure that Roslyn actually parsed the project: dump the source from a syntax tree to the build log.
            Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects.First()
                .Documents.First(i => i.FilePath.EndsWith(".cs")).GetSyntaxRoot().GetText().ToString());

            return true;
        }
    }

    public static class IEnumerableExtension
    {
        public static string ToSingleString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, string separator, string leftWrapper, string rightWrapper)
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                if (stringBuilder.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(separator))
                        stringBuilder.Append(separator);
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(leftWrapper))
                    stringBuilder.Append(leftWrapper);

                stringBuilder.Append(item.ToString());

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rightWrapper))
                    stringBuilder.Append(rightWrapper);
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

To demonstrate that it actually works, add the following lines at the end of your csproj file (just before the closing Project tag). But only if the project was already built successfully and it can find your task dll in the output folder.

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="RoslynTask"/>
  <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(OutputPath)\RoslynMsBuildTask.dll" TaskName="RoslynMsBuildTask.RoslynTask" />
  <Target Name="RoslynTask">
    <RoslynTask ReferencePath="@(ReferencePath)" Compile="@(Compile)" BaseDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
  </Target>
```

It will dump the source of your first cs file to the build output.

---

Note that other csc.exe switches (like ConditionalDirectives, output type, etc) may also matter depending on the type of analysis you are trying to do. You can also pass them to your task using this pattern. See $(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets file, CoreCompile target, Csc task for a complete list of properties that MsBuild passes to csc.exe.

Comment: Note that other switches like ConditionalDirectives, output type, etc, MAY matter depending on the type of analysis you are trying to do, but this is a great starting point!

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for the info, I've added it to my answer.

Comment: For me, this yields in the same exception. (Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Roslyn.Utilities.SerializableDataStorage')

Comment: @Imi Does this apply to your environment? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/roslyn/thread/39c0226e-7063-4701-8f44-4d5419e9e82d/ "... it seems to work if you install the CTP and have Roslyn.Services.dll in the GAC, but doesn't work if you use the NuGet package."

Answer (score -1):

This is a limitation of MSBuild.  Roslyn can't invoke MSBuild recursively during a build to determine the project properties/files/references.  In order to create a Roslyn `IProject` during in a build task, try using the `LoadFromCommandLineArgs()` method instead.  You'll need to construct your task to take the same arguments as the CscTask ends up passing to the compiler.

Hope this helps!