# Roslyn LoadProjectFromCommandLineArguments language argument?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm creating a custom MSBuild task that uses Roslyn to do some code analysis.
I've read that [you cannot call Workspace.LoadStandAloneProject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052115) and you have to use Workspace.LoadProjectFromCommandLineArguments.

OK, but what should I specify for the 2nd argument (language)? It's a **string**, not an enum, and no info on the whole wide internet. I've tried "cs", "c#", "CSharp", "vb", "vb.net" and then I gave up guessing. I alwalys get the error: "The language '...' is not supported."

Does it work at all? What's the right string for C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of ildasm-ing I've found it.

- "C#" (case sensitive, with capital 'C')
- "Visual Basic" (also case sensitive)

You can find it in the disassembly of 
Roslyn.Services.CSharp.CSharpProjectFileLoaderService::get_Language()
and
Roslyn.Services.VisualBasic.VisualBasicProjectFileLoaderService::get_Language()

Answer (score 2):

Use `LanguageNames.CSharp`.

BTW - Making a sample of such a build task has been on my todo list for a long time. If you could post the basic code (without your specific analysis) once you get it working, that would be much appreciated!