# Roslyn compilation with two assemblies?

Tags: roslyn

I have a solution with two output dlls (actually more, but lets keep it simple). Project "Special" references project "Common".

I try to write an code generator that parses some files from "Special" and place generated stub code into the project "Common". To deal with this circular reference, I need to work on code which does not compile. So I am using Roslyn.

The generator need to have some types replaced based on inheritance information, so I need to construct a compilation unit to gain access to the semantic model. Additionally, I need to replace some stuff based on the origin of the types (whether they are defined in "Special" or "Common". Or more precise: Based on global assembly attributes).

The generator must be able to be run as a MSBuild tasks.

I tried two approaches to setup my environment and I am stuck with both:

1. I tried to just load my solution within the Generator. This fails because of "Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Roslyn.Utilities.SerializableDataStorage'". Then I tried to create the solution from scratch, adding IProjects and IDocuments and I already tried LoadProjectFromCommandLineArguments as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052115/roslyn-workspace-loads-in-console-application-but-not-in-msbuild-task), but nothing seem to work for me and I get the very same exception when running from MSBuild (it runs fine when started via console).

   Anyone knows how to deal with the SerializableDataStorage exception?
2. I tried to create a Compilation and add all my cs source. But now I can't find a way to know whether my symbols came from assembly "Special" or "Common".

   Can I compile into two different assemblies using one Compilation? Or can I pass one compilation as reference to another compilation? (Is there a MetadataReference I can feed to Compilation.AddReference that points to another Compilation?)

PS: Something I haven't tried yet is to add some kind of metadata (e.g. a comment node at the start) to the syntax trees before I add them to the Compilation or use the SyntaxTree.FilePath property and some mapping, to use this information in my generator to tell whether a defined type is from "Special" or "Common". I rather would not end up doing stuff like this, as it would get messy very quickly (In reality, I have around 20 dlls).

Comment: Regarding the first issue: How did you get the binaries on the machine, and what is the "bitness" of the process where this is running?  Can you try installing the Roslyn CTP instead of through NuGet?  ALso, if it's a 64-bit process can you try running it in a 32-bit process?

Comment: I am running on 64-bit, Windows 8, little endian and indeed obtained roslyn through nuget. I don't know how to tell visual studio to run MSBuild in any specific mode (32 or 64).. I tried setting the project to "Prefer 32 bit" already, but got the same exception.

Comment: If you are using msbuild through Visual Studio, it will always use the 32-bit version.  From the command line you can launch the 64-bit version explicitly out of the %Windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319 directory.  Also - try installing the CTP MSI (which will add the Roslyn assemblies to the GAC), and see if that addresses the issue.

Comment: I should also note, that I used a *pre*-compile step in my msbuild target xml. As I understand LoadProjectFromCommandLineArguments, it executes the build.xml until "just before compiling" step, so it would surely try to execute my pre-compile target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there is a 1:1 correspondence between compilations and built assemblies, so if you need to represent both assemblies during analysis you need two compilations. To add references between them, just do `compilation.AddReference(new CompilationReference(sourceCompilation))` and symbols should import how you expect. Don't forget compilations are immutable, so if you ever fork sourceCompilation you may have to fork your referencing compilation as well.

On any given symbol, there's a property ContainingAssembly which gets you back to the assembly where the symbol came from. Make sure you set up your output names correctly on your compilations, and that will let you figure that out.